# Automatic job to check if specific element in html page has been updated

Tags: html, linux, web

I want to 'surveil' a page on a website, and get an alert (preferably an email) each time a specific element on the html page is updated. What is the best way to achieve this? I would like the job to run on an ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use cron task to schedule a script to be execute regularly

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-cron-to-automate-tasks-on-a-vps

so it would be like

```
* * * * * /path/to/script
```

and you can write your own script to fetch the website content, check element and send email

Comment: This sounds like a good way. Do you know of any good tutorials on how to write scripts? I suppose it can't be too difficult, as I program in Java and Python on a semi-regular basis.

Comment: the script be anything executable so just write in Python and set the cron task to run it